# Error de tipo en variable de bloque Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo una variable de bloque let llamada divContainer, esta podra contener un valor null o un elemento HTML segun cierta circunstancia. aqui un [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAJglgbgYQPYDswEMYpAJwFwQASAKgLIAyAoqALYhoQA%20EKArsMBALwTRIDGrOmgB0-HCHRgQ1EMLAAKAESw4SgJQBuALAAoUJADOAB3QoCJCrPlMW7TjygCh9MGIlSZtV8pNmNOrqqyGiY2Dgi6MbG9FAIABYwwFAKfijqesGoGFi4jvAhOeFiickSKADaAAwAuhB6QA) del codigo y El codigo es el siguiente:

```
let divContainer: HTMLElement | null =  document.createElement("div");
let span: HTMLElement | null = document.createElement("span");
divContainer.appendChild(span)
divContainer= divContainer.children[0]
```

El codigo anterior genera errores de typescript. He probado diferentes maneras de tipar la variable div container pero siempre recibo algun error.

Esto he probado:

```
let divContainer: HTMLElement extends HTMLElement =  document.createElement("div");
let span: HTMLElement | null = document.createElement("span");
divContainer.appendChild(span)
divContainer= divContainer.children[0]
```

La solucion seria, encontrar una forma de tipar la variable de bloque divContainer sin recibir errores. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: un error se soluciona con divContainer.appendChild(span);

Comment: En lugar de declarar `divContainer` como `HTMLElement | null`, decláralo como `Element | null`. Eso solucionará tu error.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez la solución que propones me ha funcionado, gracias.